# EF code first to new DataBase Deployement error?sqlexpress server not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

i have built the project winforms application using code first to new database i am deploying where i have installed sqlserver 2008 r2 and administrator mode but database creation fails i have attached image here

[image: ERROR]

**SOLUTIONS NEEDED**

1-By default code first to new db use

```
  .\SQLEXPRESS
```

but i have no acess to this on client pc

so How to change the server name using ef code first to new db where

```
   local SQL Express instance
```

is not present?

My sql server connecting with .\sqlexpress but on vs 2010 server explorer when i connect it with .\sqlexpress i found no database as shown by SSMS

Comment: Could you post your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you do not have SQL express instance installed on your computer. If you want to use the installed SQL Server 2008 instance, you need to add it either by using app.config or using fluent configuration.

If you have a connection string, then the problem seems that you have not declared the username or password in the connection string.

Comment: give me query what should i add till that i already now and clear by image that it need to be installed image i have only installed sql server 2008 r2?
so what to add in App.config file i have edited and added my app.config file code must check now

Comment: have you tried searching for "windows forms connection string app.config" in google?

Comment: you are talking about existing database i have no database it have to create database it self problem is `SERVER NAME` **Data Source=.\sqlexpress;** i have no acess to this on client pc at my pc i have installed local instance so it works how to give default server name mean user in ef to new db

Comment: I am not talking about an existing database; if database does not exists, EF will try creating it; you need a password and a username to connect a database or you need to have a db with trusted connection.

Comment: trusted db NOUMAN\SQLEXPRESS  but works on administrator account not on others unhandled exception while connecting database

Comment: even on client computer .\sqlexpress i have checked not connecting

Comment: db with trusted connection

Answer (score 0):

[image: answer step by step]

as i have not given permission to builtin account to be logged in